# Get the "raw" function parameter, not the value of it

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have an Obj-C method that takes a boolean, and the name of the boolean so it can be logged:

```objectivec
- (void)shouldBeEnabled:(BOOL)flag flagName:(NSString *)flagName {
  if (!flag) {
    NSLog(@"Not enabled because %@ is false", flagName);
  }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```objectivec
BOOL swizzlingEnabled = NO;
[self shouldBeEnabled:swizzlingEnabled flagName:@"swizzlingEnabled"];
```

While this works, it's really annoying to copy the parameter as a string, just so it can be logged, and leaves it open for the log to get out of sync with the actual parameter that is passed in when it gets renamed or something.

Ideally the method would drop the `flagName` parameter, but it would still work in the same way, where it would print the literal string that is used. For example:

```
[self shouldBeEnabled:swizzlingEnabled];
// prints "Not enabled because swizzlingEnabled is false"

// And it would be extremely cool if this would also work:
[self shouldBeEnabled:(someOptionHere == nil)];
// prints "Not enabled because (someOptionHere == nil) is false"
```

Is this possible at all?

(Yes I realize these code examples look very silly.. why would you create the `swizzlingEnabled` variable just to pass it into the function in the next line. Obviously in the real world app there is quite a bit more going on, but this is what it boils down to )

Comment: Maybe pass instead a custom Object? A custom class with 2 properties: `Bool` & `NSString`, and provide only class method to it: something like `[Custom allowWithName:@"flagName"]` & `[Custom disableWithName:@"flagName"]`, and you'll retrieve the name & value from there?

Comment: I don't really like to use strings like that, too easy to make a typo, compiler doesn't catch any errors.

Comment: You have "restreinted" number of different string? Then, don't put it in the parameter of the constructor: `[Custom allowForReason1]`/`[Custom disableForReason1]`, and inside that private constructor you have -(Custom *)disableForReason1 { return [[Custom alloc] initWithBool:YES flagName:PrivateReason1] }` But then, you could also use an enum: allowForReason1, disableForReason1, allowForReason2, disableForReason2, etc.

Comment: Nope, sadly not.

Comment: Then, I don't understand the "I don't really like to use strings like that, too easy to make a typo", what do you expect? Since it's to use like `[self shouldBeEnabled: [Custom allowWithName:@'FlagName"]]`